# How to increase the number of decimal places for this code?

Tags: numerics, fractals

How do I increase the number of decimal places for

```
f1 = Map[Flatten@*First]@MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &;
f2 = Flatten[Flatten[f1@CantorMesh[13]]];
f[x_] := x^(1/5)
N[Total[f@f2]/Length[f2], 10]
```

I get six decimal places instead of 10.

```
0.804028
```

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write a new `cantormesh` function that uses exact numbers instead of floating-point approximations:

```
cantormesh[0] = {{0, 1}};
cantormesh[n_Integer?Positive] := cantormesh[n] = 
  Join @@ ({{#[[1]],(2#[[1]]+#[[2]])/3},{(#[[1]]+2#[[2]])/3,#[[2]]}} & /@
    cantormesh[n-1])
```

Now the result is exact:

```
f2 = Flatten[cantormesh[13]];
f[x_] = x^(1/5);
Z = Total[f@f2]/Length[f2]
(*    long output    *)
```

Ask for 30 digits:

```
N[Z, 30]
(*    0.804027503496689833535703631763    *)
```

Comment: Here is a nonrecursive version: `cantormesh[n_Integer?NonNegative] := Nest[Replace[#, {x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ} :> Apply[Sequence, Partition[Subdivide[x, y, 3], 2]], 1] &, {{0, 1}}, n]`. As for the OP's computation itself: `With[{c = Flatten[N[cantormesh[13], 30]]}, Mean[c^(1/5)]]`.