# Creating a function which lists all points in the cantor set?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, intervals

How do we create a function which lists all points of the Cantor set? I want it to be listed as...

```
C[x_]:=.....
```

I don't know how to create a nested table which removes the middle thirds of the interval $[0,1]$, then $[1/9,2/9],[7/9,8/9]$ from $[0,1],...$. How do we do this? I am hoping we can include points that are not at the endpoints of the remaining interval such as $x=1/4,3/10$.

**Edit: I tried using the answer from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218321/34171).**

```
cantormesh[0] = {{0, 1}};
cantormesh[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 cantormesh[n] = 
  Join @@ ({{#[[1]], (2 #[[1]] + #[[2]])/3}, {(#[[1]] + 2 #[[2]])/
         3, #[[2]]}} & /@ cantormesh[n - 1])
```

But how do I make the cantor mesh number approach infinity so that I get all the listed points. How do I set up a function using variable  `n` set equal to `CantorMesh[n]` which lists all these points.

Comment: Pretty sure the function in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218321) solves your problem.

Comment: @J.M. I am not sure how to extract the points. A quick answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @Arbuja Have you tried using the code in the linked answer? Have you tried running e.g. `cantormesh[3]`? You should explain how precisely the output of that function is not what you need?

Comment: @MarcoB I explained in my post.

Comment: First you say that you want to "lists all points of the Cantor set"; now you say "I get a blank plot", which is an entirely different thing. Make up your mind!

Comment: @J.M. As the cantor mesh number approaches infinity I should get all the points right. Is there a better way?

Comment: "approach infinity so that I get all the listed points" - so if I understood you correctly, you want a list containing infinitely many points, that is infinitely long?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, an infinitely long list. Infinitely many points.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about how to plot it, here is one way.

```
NumberLinePlot[Interval /@ cantormesh[2], Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]